# base64_decode is not working with php8.1 & magento 2.4.4

Tags: php, magento2, php-8.1, magento2.4.4

We are using Magento 2.4.4 on php8.1 and one of the magento core file is having a method which is using `base64_decode()` method.
Can you please suggest alternate of `base64_decode();`

`$filterString = base64_decode($filterString);`

Comment: Have you considered that you may have invalid data or a bug in your code? It's very unlikely that PHP/8.1 broke a core feature like that and nobody else noticed.

Comment: Yes @ÁlvaroGonzález - you are right, issue was with empty data. Thanks so much